How can I enable the proof size recorder during runtime testing?
I am attempting to enable and utilize the proof_size recorder host function in the runtime, but I am stuck in the runtime testing.
The default TestExternalities does not enable the recorder, so I modified the TestExternalities generation as shown in the following code:
pub fn new_test_ext_with_recorder() -> TestExternalities {
    let mut storage = frame_system::GenesisConfig::<Test>::default()
        .build_storage()
        .unwrap();

    pallet_balances::GenesisConfig::<Test> {
        balances: vec![(
            H160::from_str("0x1234500000000000000000000000000000000000").unwrap(),
            12345,
        )],
    }
    .assimilate_storage(&mut storage)
    .expect("Pallet balances storage can be assimilated");

    let recorder: Recorder<Blake2Hasher> = Default::default();
    let backend: TrieBackend<PrefixedMemoryDB<Blake2Hasher>, _> =
        (storage.clone(), Default::default()).into();
    let root = backend.root().clone();
    let db = backend.into_storage();

    let backend_with_reorder = TrieBackendBuilder::new(db, root)
        .with_recorder(recorder.clone())
        .build();

    let mut test_ext: TestExternalities = storage.into();
    // Change backend and register rextension
    test_ext.backend = backend_with_reorder;
    test_ext.register_extension(ProofSizeExt::new(recorder));

    test_ext
}

Runtime test cases wrote as:
#[test]
fn test_proof_size() {
    let mut test_ext = new_test_ext_with_recorder();
    test_ext.execute_with(|| {
        let pre_proof_size = cumulus_primitives_storage_weight_reclaim::get_proof_size();
        println!("proof size pre init value: {}", pre_proof_size.unwrap());

        // Update storage items manually
        for i in 100..105 {
            AccountCodes::<Test>::insert(H160::from_low_u64_be(i), vec![i as u8; 500]);
        }

        println!("proof size post 1: {:?}", cumulus_primitives_storage_weight_reclaim::get_proof_size());

        // Update storage items manually
        for i in 70..90 {
            AccountCodes::<Test>::insert(H160::from_low_u64_be(i), vec![i as u8; 500]);
        }
        println!("proof size post 2: {:?}", cumulus_primitives_storage_weight_reclaim::get_proof_size());
    });
}

The console output is:
proof size pre init value: 0
proof size post 1: Some(0)
proof size post 2: Some(0)
test tests::proof_size_tests::test_proof_size ... ok

The expected testing result is that the proof size output should increase after the storage is updated. I have tested it with other storage operations; sometimes it works, but not always.
